# C# if DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") is equals to

Tags: c#, datetime

I made a script that check if the current time is equals to a string, the code is:

```
    string ore = Properties.Settings.Default.oreChiusura;
string minuti = Properties.Settings.Default.minutiChiusura;
var t1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
var t2 = ore + ":" + minuti;

if(t1 == t2)
{
     //Stuff
}
```

the problem is, if "minuti" is like 01....09 it not work, it work only if is a number without the starting 0.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are saying that `DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")` returns, for example "17:4" and not "17:04"?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6FjE3s

Answer (score 3):

Your example is a perfect illustration to the principle that you should not be doing comparisons in strings if you can do them in integers:

```
var adesso = DateTime.Now;
var oreAdesso = adesso.Hour;
var minutiAdesso = adesso.Minute;
if (oreAdesso == ore && minutiAdesso == minuti) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
string ore = Properties.Settings.Default.oreChiusura;
string minuti = Properties.Settings.Default.minutiChiusura;
var t1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
var t2 = ore.PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + minuti.PadLeft(2, '0');

if(t1 == t2)
{
     //Stuff
}
```

BUT! It is strongly advised to change your code to use `TimeSpan` setting instead of `oreChiusura` and `minutiChiusura` settings, and then compare `TimeSpan` values instead of strings.

For example:

```
var t1 = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
var t2 = Properties.Settings.Default.Chiusura;
if(t1 == t2)
{
     //Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by casting `ore` and `minuti` to int, and then comparing the values.

```
int ore = Convert.ToInt32(Properties.Settings.Default.oreChiusura);
int minuti = Convert.ToInt32(Properties.Settings.Default.minutiChiusura);
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;

if(t1.Hour == ore && t1.Minute ==  minuti)
{
   //Stuff
}
```

This code compares true values of hours and minutes, instead of their string values.